# Проблема с получением ответа от API на русском

Tags: php, laravel, api, gpt

**Всем привет!** 
В своем Laravel приложении я столкнулся со странной проблемой. 
Получаю ответ от api, но на русском всё в пробелах, а на английском всё ок. Подскажите пожалуйста как пофиксить?
Снизу представлен скриншот проблемы :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контроллера (chatcontroller.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\MessageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Message;
use OpenAI\Laravel\Facades\OpenAI;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    private $openAIRequest;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->openAIRequest = Http::withoutVerifying()
            ->withOptions(['timeout' => 120])
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('openai.api_key'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]);
    }

    public function messages(Request $request, MessageRequest $messageRequest)
    {
        
        $prompt = $messageRequest->input('prompt');
        $proglang = $messageRequest->input('proglang');
        $framework = $messageRequest->input('framework');
        $size = $messageRequest->input('size');
        $lang = $messageRequest->input('lang');
        $message = 'Задокументируйте код на языке программирования: ' . $proglang . ' с использованием фреймворка: ' . $framework .
            ' Документация должна быть в формате: ' . $size . ' Объект - предназначение' . ' и написана на ' . $lang . ' языке.' .
            ' Код, который необходимо документировать: ' . $prompt . ' Если в поле для кода будет короткий код, то мы его всё равно описываем, а если код отсутствует, то сообщи об этом. Текже не повторяй в своем ответе мой запрос, сконкретизируся на документации';

       Message::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'prompt' => $prompt,
            'proglang' => $proglang,
            'framework' => $framework,
            'size' => $size,
            'lang' => $lang,
        ]);

        return $this->askToChatGPT($message);
    }

    private function askToChatGPT($message)
    {
        $question = $message;
        return response()->stream(function () use ($question) {
            $stream = OpenAI::completions()->createStreamed([
                'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
                'prompt' => $question,
                'max_tokens' => 2000,
                'temperature' => 0.3,
            ]);
    
            foreach ($stream as $response) {
                $text = trim($response->choices[0]->text);
                if (connection_aborted()) {
                    break;
                }
    
                echo "\n";
                echo $text;
                echo "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }, 200, [
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
            'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
            'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8',
        ]);
    }    

}
```

А также скрипт страницы с API :

```
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $("#ask-chatgpt-form");
            var formData = form.serialize();
            var textarea = form.find('textarea[name="prompt"]');

            var selectedproglang = $('select[name="proglang"]').val();
            formData += '&proglang=' + selectedproglang;


            var selectedframework = $('select[name="framework"]').val();
            formData += '&framework=' + selectedframework;

            var selectedsize = $('select[name="size"]').val();
            formData += '&size=' + selectedsize;

            var selectedlang = $('select[name="lang"]').val();
            formData += '&lang=' + selectedlang;

            generateChatBoxMessage(false, textarea.val());
            textarea.val('');
            function generateChatBoxMessage(isChatGPTMessage, messageText) {
            var template = isChatGPTMessage ? $("#chatgpt-message-box-template").html() : $("#user-message-box-template").html();
            var messageBox = $(template);
            messageBox.find('#message-box-text').text(messageText);
            $('#chat-box').append(messageBox);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'chatgpt/ask',
                data: formData,
                success: function(answer) {
                    generateChatBoxMessage(true, answer);
                },
            });
        });
        const source = new EventSource('chatgpt/ask' + encodeURIComponent(input));
        source.addEventListener('update', function(event) {
            if (event.data === "<END_STREAMING_SSE>") {
                source.close();
                return;
            }
            result.innerText += event.data
        });
        // Обновляем скрытое поле при выборе значения в с-електоре
        $('select').change(function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(selectedValue);
        });     
    </script>
```

> P.s. Если вам недостаточно информации или кода,то напишите в комментариях и я обязательно дополню вопрос!

Comment: Также закинул ответ в консоль.Только там слова не через пробел, а через строку

Comment: залогируй какой текст отправляется, если дебага нет, обмажся логами и найдешь проблемное место

Comment: да я уже пытался в консоль вывести и в пустой див, всё равно английский норм выводится , а Русский нет

Comment: в функции которая отправляет текст - текст нормально записан?

Comment: вроде да, но почему то русский через пробелы а английский норм

Comment: вроде или точно? возможно баг со стороны гпт